# Apache and Yarn ports

Tags: apache, server, hadoop-yarn

I want to configure both apache and yarn servers on the same machine. Default web port is 80 and 443 for ssl as far as I know.

Is that possible for both services to share the same ports? What I need is:

http(s)://example1.com - go to apache server
http(s)://example2.com - go to yarn

I know I can configure it so I call:
http(s)://example1.com:3000 or other port. It's not intuitive for users however.

Or... make htaccess rule to redirect example1.com:80 to example1.com:81 for example? Or somehow internally redirect from apache to yarn...? :)

I'm pretty newbie in configuring servers... I always used default settings and vhosts and it was just enough. In fact I've never work with yarn at all so any advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can using haproxy or squid proxy, to loading balancing, or you can set on domain server to set pointing the domain, but you must set other port on of app, on this case we must try to easy access without type the port on the address bar

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

apache in vhosts configuration is redirecting specific domain traffic from :80 to :3000 and node is run on 3000 port.